# Killed my internet connection on kali

Tags: kali-linux

I tried doing something from the internet and failed big time. Also i killed my internet connection. Every time i try to ping google, this is what i get [image]

i tried to change wlan0mon to wlan0 and ran some commands i saw on the internet

iwconfig gives me this [image]

ifconfig gives me this[image]

Comment: "doing something from the internet" - undo that?

Comment: `I tried doing something from the internet and failed big time. Also i killed my internet connection.` --- What did you try doing from the internet that failed big time?  How did you kill the internet connection?

Comment: i did try to switch wlan0mon to wlan0 ran some commands i saw on the internet

Comment: What `commands I saw on the internet` did you use EXACTLY?  In order to understand what may have gone wrong, specific answers are needed, please.

Answer (score 2):

If ping reports name or service not known I would guess that you have a problem with your dns service. Have you tried to ping an ip instead of "google.com"? You can find out the coresponding ip to an website by tools like

http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.cgi

Comment: that works but my firefox still does not work

Comment: So this strongly suggests that your DNS is not answering. The DNS configuration is stored at "/etc/resolv.conf" you could execute       “nameserver 8.8.8.8” >> /etc/resolv.conf     which will append the current configuration with the google public DNS. (You could choose any DNS server but I would recommend this for testing purposes). To further diagnoe what went wrong before executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `ip link`. See if the interface is down. If so, you can run `ip link set INTERFACE up` and try again. Try using nmtui and see what it says when you try  to activate a network with it. If no networks show up, then that means the interface is down. If it errors there is another problem.

According to your picture, you are on a network, so hopefully these aren’t the problem. Try connecting elsewhere in case it is not the computer, or try something other than ping and see what happens.

Comment: root@kali:~# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:d9:b5:88:e8:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:2b:73:dc:90:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 this is what i get after ip link

Comment: Is this a computer where you are able to try other Wifi networks, eg not a desktop? It sounds like it’s connecting just fine. What was the thing that messed it up in the first place? That’s critical